# How to automate the export of the ARM template for Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I have an Azure Data Factory in live mode
I want to set up a daily script or processing (at the end of the day) which automate the export of the ARM template and deposits it on a local disk.
I did some research to try to do it with powershell but it seems that it is not feasible for ADF.

Would you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The below MSFT doc can help with your ask :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer
Is it a DevOps command ? my ADF is on line mode and I don't configure DevOps

Comment: any another possibility ?